# Shopping Cart does not display updated info

Tags: jsf-2

I'm using WildFly 9.0 and IntelliJ 14 Ultimate
I can add items to the cart- and they can be viewed using a PrimeFaces data table on ViewCart.xhtml
There is a button to delete each cart item- which works.
Faces-config has been edited to return back to the ViewCart.xhtml page when the button is clicked; which seems to be the case.
The PROBEM: Cart is still showing the original list, before the item was deleted. 
If I go to the product catalogue and return back to ViewCart.xhtml, the executed changes are reflected in the cart. Please can someone help?

Here is the ViewCart.xhtml page

```
<body>
<h:outputText value="Cart List"
              style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 18px;  font-weight: 900;" />
<h:form name="ViewProductsManagedBean">

    <p:dataTable id="cartTable" var="cartList"
                 value="#{ViewProductsManagedBean.cart}"  <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Delete  Cart Item "
                              style="font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:commandButton action="#{ViewProductsManagedBean.removeItemFromCart(cartList.itemcode)}"> </h:commandButton>


        </p:column>

        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

now the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="ViewProductsManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ViewProductsManagedBean {


    public String removeItemFromCart(String itemCode){
        return cartFunctions.removeItemFromCart(itemCode);
    }



}
```

The facade that "talks" to the business logic

```
    @Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class CartFacade {


public String removeItemFromCart(String itemCode){
     return cartBean.removeItemFromCart(itemCode);
}
```

}

The cart been looks like follows:

```
@Stateful
@Local(ShoppingCartLocal.class)
@Remote(ShoppingCart.class)
@SessionScoped
public class ShoppingCartBean implements ShoppingCartLocal, ShoppingCart {


    public String removeItemFromCart(String itemCode){
        for(Orderitem ord:cartItems){
            if(itemCode.equals(ord.getItemcode())){
                cartItems.remove(ord);
                System.out.println("Item removed " + itemCode);

            }
        }

        return "ViewCart";
    }
```

here is the full cart bean

```
 package com.shop.cart;

/**
 * Created by LalinPethiyagoda on 30/07/2015.
 */


@Stateful
@Local(ShoppingCartLocal.class)
@Remote(ShoppingCart.class)
@SessionScoped
public class ShoppingCartBean implements ShoppingCartLocal, ShoppingCart {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName ="Shop")
    private EntityManager cartEntityManager;
    private CustomerManager customerManagerBean;
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> cartItems = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private List<Orderitem> cartItemsReturn = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setCartItems(CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }



    private  CustomerEntity customer;


    public ShoppingCartBean(){}


@Override
    public List<Orderitem> getCartItemsReturn() {
        return cartItemsReturn;
    }
    public void setCartItemsReturn(List<Orderitem> cartItemsReturn) {
        this.cartItemsReturn = cartItemsReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addCartItem(ProductEntity product, int quantityPurchased){
        com.shop.entity.Orderitem basketItem=new Orderitem();
        Locale currentLocale = new Locale("en", "GB");
        double subTotal;

            // check for duplicate entry.
        for (Orderitem itemsIntheCart : cartItems) {
            if (itemsIntheCart.getItemcode().equals(product.getItemcode())) {
                    return false;
            }
        }

            basketItem.setItemcode(product.getItemcode());
            basketItem.setItemdescription(product.getItemdescription());
            basketItem.setUnitprice(product.getUnitprice());
            basketItem.setQuantitypurchased(quantityPurchased);
            subTotal = quantityPurchased * basketItem.getUnitprice();
            Double currencyAmount = new Double(subTotal);
            NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
            currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount);
            basketItem.setSubtotal(currencyAmount);
            cartItems.add(basketItem);
            return true;
    }

    public String removeItemFromCart(String itemCode){
        for(Orderitem ord:cartItems){
            if(itemCode.equals(ord.getItemcode())){
                cartItems.remove(ord);

                System.out.println("Item removed " + itemCode);

            }
        }

        return "ViewCart";
    }


@Override
    public CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> viewCartItems(){
    return this.cartItems;
    }

    @Override
    public CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> getCartItems(){
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<Orderitem> cartItemList = this.cartItems;
        for(Orderitem x:cartItemList){
            System.out.println(x.getItemdescription());
        }
        return cartItemList;
    }


    public  CustomerEntity getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public  void setCustomer(CustomerEntity customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public void removeCartItem(int itemCode){
        System.out.println("hello");

    }

    @Override
    public double getTotal(){
        double total=0;
        for(Orderitem bItem:getCartItems()){
            total = total + bItem.getSubtotal();
        }
        return total;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void exit(){
        persistCartItems();
        stopSession();
    }
    @Override
    public void persistCartItems() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Remove
    public void stopSession(){
        System.out.println("saved- all done - object detached from object pool");
    }

    public void assignCartToCustomer(){
        customer = customerManagerBean.getVerifiedCustomer();
    }

    public CustomerEntity getCustomerAssociatedWithTheCart(){
        return this.customer;
    }
    @Remove
    public void remove() {
        cartItems = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementQuantity() {
    }
    @Override
    public void decrementQuantity() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your full ShoppingCartBean?  Also, is your button using an ajax call?

Comment: @TerrenceCurran Done! No Ajax at the moment